# How to set a preselected option with Nebular, nb-select

Tags: html, angular, nebular

https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/select/overview#nbselectcomponent

Is it possible to have a preselected value when the page is loaded ?

Answer (score 3):

There exists an [issue with dynamic data](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/2145), but with static data, it works as described in the documentation you mentioned:

HTML:

```
<nb-select placeholder="Select Showcase" [(selected)]="selectedItem">
      <nb-option value="">Option empty</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="0">Option 0</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="1">Option 1</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="2">Option 2</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="3">Option 3</nb-option>
      <nb-option value="4">Option 4</nb-option>
    </nb-select>
```

TS: `selectedItem = '2';`

Comment: Don't work... See issue: https://github.com/akveo/nebular/issues/1921

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<nb-select id="theme" [selected]="currentTheme" (selectedChange)="changeTheme($event)" status="primary">
        <nb-select-label [innerHtml]="selectedTheme"></nb-select-label>
        <nb-option langg *ngFor="let theme of themes" [value]="theme.value"> {{ theme.name | langg }}</nb-option>
      </nb-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue when dynamically generating options for nbSelect multiple form controller and show already selected items. I could achieve it as follows.

file.html

```
<nb-select
  fullWidth
  placeholder="{{ title }}"
  formControlName="value"
  multiple
>
    <nb-option
      *ngFor="let option of options"
       value="{{ option.key }}"
    >
      {{ option.value }}
    </nb-option>
</nb-select>
```

file.ts

```
let selectedOptionKeys = ["48c50001-dd7e-11eb-ad02-1d1ad36d5a53", "bc2edbd4-dfa4-11eb-a78c-5d1ee44adbd1", "636348eb-e992-11eb-9bb8-71a14542f9ee"]
this.formBuilder.group({
     value: new FormControl(selectedOptionKeys),
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ts :
constructor(){
 this.selectedArea = this.Areas.filter(x => x.areaId == this.achead.areaId)[0];
}
html:
<nb-select fullWidth placeholder="Select Area" [(selected)]="selectedArea" name="areaId">
                            <nb-option *ngFor="let area of Areas" [value]="area">
                                {{ area.areaName }}
                            </nb-option>
                        </nb-select>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
[(selected)]=''
```

That's what I had to add in `<nb-select`>.